# Consider a set S1 from a domain. What is an algorithm to find that S1 has no set as a subset from the domain.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am trying to come across an algorithm.
The question is written as clearly and concisely as I could.

Suppose there is a set S1 from a domain. Indicate an algorithm to find that S1 has no set as its subset from the domain.
Even if S1 has a set as its subset from its domain, consider an S2 and find the algorithm.

I came across the answer that the algorithm should be a recursive one. I am not sure if this is true or not. It's easy to write an algorithm to find all the subsets of a set. but to indicate a specific algorithm to find that a set has no subsets from the given domain D is entirely different.

Thanks for the response in advance.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to write clearly but it's still not clear to me. Do you mean that for a given family ("domain") $\mathcal{D}$  of subsets of some set $X$ and a given set $S_1 \in \mathcal{D}$ the algorithm should decide whether there is a proper subset $S_2 \subsetneq S_1$ such that $S_2 \in \mathcal{D}$? Also, is $\mathcal{D}$ some specific family or is it given to the algorithm as part of the input?

Comment: @Adayah No, more like:

Comment: No, more like:    There is a domain of sets {S1, S2, S3... Sn}. Now,  a single set from this domain, consider it s1, does not have any of the other sets as its subset. what should be the algorithm to find it? What you said, D is not a domain of subsets of some set X. Instead, it is a domain of sets. Also, as you said S2⊊S1, should be S2 is not a subset of any of the set S from the domain D. I hope this clears the confusion